# Python Code. What is wrong with this basic code?

Tags: python

﻿**Just doing some basic code and then this error popped up. I have no idea what I should fix everything seems fine. (Using Python)**

Code:

```
dict = {'name':'Bob','ref':'Python','sys':'Win'}
print('\nReference:',dict['ref'])
print('n\Keys:',dict.keys()
del dict[ 'name' ]
dict['user']='Tom'
print('\nDictionary:',dict)
print('\nIs There A name Key?:','name' in dict)

C:\Python>dictionary.py
File "C:\Python\dictionary.py", line 4
del dict[ 'name' ]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntaxer code here
```

Comment: Count the parentheses on the previous line.

Comment: Did your Python really say `invalid syntaxer code here`?

Comment: That is strange. It did say line 4 but the problem was on line 3. I have no idea why python did that it confused me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis on line 3. It should be:

```
print('n\Keys:',dict.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks, :). I can't believe I missed something as small as that.